# Cannot Interrupt HttpClient.GetStreamAsync by means of CancellationToken in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I'm trying to send an http request to an AXIS Camera in order to receive a stream.
Everything works fine except that I can't get to use CancellationToken to cancel the request when it is no more needed. I've the following architecture:

Blazor client:

```
// LiveCamera.razor
<img src="CameraSystem/getStream" onerror="[...]" alt="">
```

ASP.NET Core Server:

```
// CameraSystemController.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CameraSystemController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("getStream")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStream()
    {
        Stream stream = await Device_CameraStandard.GetStream();
        if (stream != null) {
            Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(stream, _contentTypeStreaming) {
                EnableRangeProcessing = true
            };
            return result;
        } else {
            return new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
        }
    }
}
```

Class accessing the camera:

```
// Device_CameraStandard.cs
internal class Device_CameraStandard
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private System.Timers.Timer _keepAliveTimer;
    
    internal Device_CameraStandard() {
        _keepAliveTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _keepAliveTimer.Interval = 3000;
        _keepAliveTimer.Elapsed += KeepAliveTimeout;
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        [...]
    }
    
    internal async Task<Stream> GetStream()
    {
        return await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://[...]/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?&camera=1", _tokenSource.Token);
    }
    
    // Invoked periodically by client from LiveCamera.razor.cs, not included here
    internal void KeepAlive()
    {
        LLogger.Debug("KeepAlive!");
        _keepAliveTimer.Stop();
        _keepAliveTimer.Start();
    }
    
    private void KeepAliveTimeout(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LLogger.Debug("Timeout!");
        _keepAliveTimer.Stop();
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        _tokenSource.Dispose();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```

However, even if all clients leave LiveCamera.razor page and the _keepAliveTimer elapses and the CancellationTokenSource is canceled, the request is not canceled. I can see it from the fact that bandwidth usage does not decreases (the "receiving" bandwitdh, indicating that Server is still receiving data from camera), it only decreases if I close the browser tab.

Could you please help me to understand what am I doing wrong? Thanks

**EDIT:** In the end, even after following the suggestion of observing the token in all code parts where the returned stream was used, included the controller, I ended up discovering that the tag

```
// LiveCamera.razor
<img src="CameraSystem/getStream" onerror="[...]" alt="">
```

was causing the client to never stop sending requests. Thus I had to use a workaround to force client to stop sending requests before leaving LiveCamera.razor page.

Comment: You're probably already reading the stream when the timeout occurs. Your [...] code needs to observe the token as well.

Comment: You're probably right. I've included the missing part of code, where the stream is used to create and return a FileStreamResult. I suppose I'll have to put that part of code inside a Task and pass to it the CancellationToken that Device_CameraStandard.GetStream() will need to return.

Comment: I ended up discovering that the client never stopped sending requests, so the token could not solve the problem. I had to force the client to stop making requests before leaving the page. I've edited the question with these new informations. So the topic may be considered closed, even if the title is not very appropriate considering what the actual solution was. Should I write this as a separate answer?